# Aside from higher resolution, what are the benefits and drawbacks of a printer with 1 picoliter droplets vs 2 picoliter droplets?

Tags: printing, printer

I'm looking at inkjet printers, and some higher-end models have 1 picoliter droplets.  The lower-end models have 2 picoliter droplets.  I assume the smaller droplets allow higher-resolution printing, but are there any other benefits or drawbacks, such as lower ink consumption or increased likelihood of clogging?

Answer (score 3):

Inkjets create shades of colors via dithering, so smaller droplets means finer dithering and better looking colors.